# knitr error when using lua-filter/task-list.lua

Tags: lua, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I am trying to use task-list.lua to create square checkboxs. The following codes were included in yaml.

```
output:
  html_document:
    pandoc_args:
      - --lua-filter=task-list.lua
```

When I run the file in R-studio on a mac, everything works fine. However, I couldn't manage to make it work on Windows. I updated `R-Studio`, `R markdown`, `markdown`, `knitr` and other dependicies, and placed the lua filter task-list.lua in `~/.pandoc/filters/task-list.lua.` 
Here is the error `Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 5`.

By the way, without

```
   pandoc_args:
     - --lua-filter=task-list.lua
```

it works fine.

With

```
pandoc_args:
  - --filter
  - --lua-filter=task-list.lua
```

it says

```
Error running filter --lua-filter=task-list.lua:
Could not find executable --lua-filter=task-list.lua
```

Any suggestion why it doesn't work and how to make this work on windows using knitr? Thank you!

Comment: Pandoc error 5 is a template error. Is your file UTF-8?

Comment: Hi Jan, Thank you for the hint! The file is in UTF-8. It was originally created on a Mac.

Comment: Have you tried updating pandoc on Windows?